# How do I stop SwiftUI from reloading WKWebView page that I am using via UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview, uiviewrepresentable

My code sets the navigation bar title it gets from web page, but everytime this causes the whole WKWebView to reload... The page is quite heavy so consumes a lot of time. Same behaviour when using button to set title.

```swift
struct TransitScreen: View, HandlerDelegate {

    var urlRequest: URLRequest
    @State var pageTitle = "Title 1"

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            KSWebView(urlRequest: urlRequest, delegate: self) // WKWebView using UIViewRepresentable
             
            NavigationLink("Go", destination: Text("Some Data"))
                
            Button(action: {
               pageTitle = "replaced \(Date().toSeconds())"
            }){
               Text("Change title")
            }
            
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(pageTitle))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }


    func process(data: String){
        pageTitle = data
    }

}
```

Is there anyway to stop this from happening? or another method to update navigationBarTitle?

Comment: How do you know that the WKWebView gets reloaded?

Comment: The webpage reloads showing loading animation which is triggered when page is loaded or refreshed

Answer (score 6):

Found source of problem

```swift
// KSWebView.swift

 func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
   uiView.load(urlRequest)
  }
```

changed this to

```swift
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        // TODO: Check this hacky code and find some replacement
        let headerHeight = CGFloat(100)
        let webViewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - headerHeight
        let webViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: headerHeight, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: webViewHeight)

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: webViewFrame, configuration: config())
        webView.load(urlRequest)
        self.webView = webView
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {

    }
```

This stops the view from loading request everytime its updated.